# Overloading __getitem__() for two key types in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, overloading

I've got a collection of users with two types of IDs (a_id, b_id) where one is a positive integer and the other is a six-letter string. For my collection class, I'd like to be able to look up users using either type of ID.

Is there something wrong with using `__contains__` and `__getitem__` for either type of ID?

```
class UserList:
    def __init__(self, users_json):
        self.a_ids = {}
        self.b_ids = {}
        for user in users_json:
            a_id = user['a_id']
            b_id = user['b_id']
            self.a_ids[a_id] = user
            self.b_ids[b_id] = user

    def __contains__(self, some_id):
        return some_id in self.a_ids or some_id in self.b_ids

    def __getitem__(self, some_id):
        try:
            return self.a_ids[some_id]
        except KeyError:
            return self.b_ids[some_id]
```

**Update:** This is for Python 3.x, and there is no implementation of `__setitem__`; updating users is handled in separate API functions.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide more code? Do you have a `__setitem__`? Are you using Python 3.3+? The answer to all of these could make a drastically different answer.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Thanks for your input. I've clarified on those two questions: No, and yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- From Python 3.3, the collections module added [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap).
  Utilizing this class can simplify your code.
- You should probably make `self.a_ids` and `self.b_ids` a list. And index to get which one you want, such as `self.ids[0]`. This list is created when using `ChainMap` anyway too.

And so I'd change your code to something more like:

```
from collections import ChainMap


class UserList:
    def __init__(self, users):
        self._lookup = ChainMap({}, {})
        self.ids = self._lookup.maps
        for user in users:
            self.ids[0][user['a_id']] = user
            self.ids[1][user['b_id']] = user

    def __contains__(self, some_id):
        return some_id in self._lookup

    def __getitem__(self, some_id):
        return self._lookup[some_id]
```

Alternately, you could subclass `ChainMap`, and not need to write any of the methods.

```
from collections import ChainMap


class UserList(ChainMap):
    def __init__(self, users):
        super().__init__({}, {})
        for user in users:
            self.maps[0][user['a_id']] = user
            self.maps[1][user['b_id']] = user
```

However, at that point, there's not much benefit to using a class. And so I'd just use a raw `ChainMap`.